# Alternative definition of an active constraint

Tags: optimization, constraints

In constrained optimization, an *active* constraint is generally taken to mean one whose inequality sign can be changed into an equality sign without affecting the optimum. However, I would like to have a term to mean a constraint which would lead to a different result if it were not present.

Case in point:
$$
\min x^2 + y^2 \\
\text{s.t.}\ x + y \geq 0
$$
What should I call the constraint $x+y\geq0$ if I want to say that it wouldn't have made a difference if it were not present?

Answer (score 0):

Active means that the solution changes if the constraint is removed.
What you want is the following
Active and tight vs active and not tight.